# How would I make a discord.js subscription system

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

Hello there I was wondering how to make a premium system, I'm not sure whether to see if in the support server they have a role, when they buy the subscription, the database updates, I would have to do the database manually, please let me know what's the best option

Comment: Please specify your question. What database you would like to use, how you would like to do it etc

Comment: 1. Hello there
2. I use mongodb
3. I'm not sure if it would be better to have it on a different bot account or have it as the same bot I'm just trying to find a way to do it

Thanks @JoeMoore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a collection that holds the ids of guilds with premium, and use another bot account (similar to dyno and dyno premium) that is for subscribers.

Your question is still quite broad, but you should also consider user friendliness - will there be a recovery option, contact details etc. You should also possibly save the `userID` of the subscriber, in case their server is deleted or they want to migrate a subscription.

Comment: Okay thanks! I will take a look at this, if it works I will accept it.

Comment: Also, how would it go through the payment, I have a website would it be able to automatically store the user and guild id to the database?

Comment: You would have to set up a website, yet. Please make sure to research laws on taking payments and virtual product - they are a complete nightmare if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: okay then

I will also try and find a way to do something like -addpremium [guildid] and it will add it to the database.

Comment: and also i will do -claimpremium so someone can claim premium for a server

Comment: You should make sure the user has the correct permissions before adding the permium for a server, since randoms shouldnt be able to go into any server and claim premium. If this answer was correct, please accept it :) I will be around to help whenever - my discord is in my profile

Comment: Okay thanks I will accept please send me a message/friend me my user is yourgrandma!#8888

Comment: Youre not accepting friend requests, add Protocol#0001

Comment: Oh okay thanks I will do!